# display date in dd.mm.yyyy format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a date like `var string = 2013-02-22`. I want to convert it into `22.02.2013`. How can I do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the textual representation of the date you can use a regular expression:

```
var string = '2013-02-22';
var patt = /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/;
var dates = patt.exec(string);

if (dates && dates.length === 4) {
    alert(dates[3] + '.' + dates[2] + '.' + dates[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). It is a free open-source javascript library for working with dates.